# UWP app.manifest default language not setting to en-US

Tags: .net, visual-studio, localization, uwp, resource-files

I have 2 language .resw file set under string folder
String -> en-US -> Resources.resw
String -> fr-FR -> Resources.resw
When i change my language to english or france, the behaviour is as expected. But when i change my language to Arabic, then the default language mentioned in app.manifest is en-US which should be displayed, but it is displaying the previously set language. What is the cause?

Comment: I suspect that you changed the language without also restarting the app.  Do keep in mind that closing your app does not stop it from running.  Use Task Manager to kill the suspended process.

Comment: No. I am closing my app. I checked the process and nothing is opened. When it works fine for the available language, how does the default language is alone not working.

Comment: What is the display language of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default UWP app loads in the language the system's culture is set, if you want the app to load into a specific culture then use the property [PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh972398).

Also for more details refer the following link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/manage-language-and-region

Comment: Thank you. With this option "PrimaryLanguageOverride", i was able to change my code and it worked.